# T-SQL retornar valor modificado

Tags: sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Implementar un procedimiento AumentarCostosPlanta que reciba por parámetro: un Id de
Planta, un porcentaje y un rango de fechas. El procedimiento debe aumentar en el
porcentaje dado, para esa planta, los costos de mantenimiento que se dieron en ese rango
de fechas. Esto tanto para mantenimientos de tipo “OPERATIVO” donde se aumenta el
costo por concepto de mano de obra (no se aumentan las horas, solo el costo) como de
tipo “NUTRIENTES” donde se debe aumentar los costos por concepto de uso de producto
(no se debe aumentar ni los gramos de producto usado ni actualizar nada del maestro de
productos)
El procedimiento debe retornar cuanto fue el aumento total de costo en dólares para la
planta en cuestión.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spu_AumentarCostoPlanta @idPlanta numeric(5), @porcentaje numeric(5,2), @fechaDesde datetime, @fechaHasta datetime
as
begin
    update Operativo set Costo_Trabajo =  Costo_Trabajo + (Costo_Trabajo * (@porcentaje/100))
    where Operativo.Mantenimiento_Id in (select m.Mantenimiento_Id From Mantenimiento m
                                            where m.Fecha_Hora between @fechaDesde and @fechaHasta 
                                            and m.Planta_Id in (select p.Id_Planta from Planta p
                                                                    where p.Id_Planta = @idPlanta))
    update Producto_Nutrientes set costo_usd = costo_usd + (costo_usd * (@porcentaje / 100))
    where Producto_Nutrientes.Nutriente_Id in (select n.Nutriente_Id from Nutriente n
                                                where n.Mantenimiento_Id in (select m.Mantenimiento_Id from Mantenimiento m
                                                                            where m.Fecha_Hora between @fechaDesde and @fechaHasta
                                                                            and m.Planta_Id in (select p.Id_Planta from Planta p)))
end
```

Buenas, para este código me piden lo detallado arriba. Lo tengo todo hecho solo me falta esta parte "El procedimiento debe retornar cuanto fue el aumento total de costo en dólares para la
planta en cuestión"
No se como haría para retornar el aumento en dólares una vez ya hice este aumento.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas pero si es la diferencia entre los Costo_Trabajo y costo_usd anterior y después de la actualización tal vez este código te sirva, no es muy "bonito" pero funciona

```
    DECLARE @Costo_TrabajoAnterior AS float
    ,@Costo_TrabajoActual AS float
    ,@costo_usdAnterior AS float
    ,@costo_usdActual AS float

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempd..#CostoTrabajo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CostoTrabajo
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempd..#Costousd') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Costousd

    select m.Mantenimiento_Id 
    INTO #CostoTrabajo
    From Mantenimiento m
                where m.Fecha_Hora between @fechaDesde and @fechaHasta 
                and m.Planta_Id in (select p.Id_Planta from Planta p
                                        where p.Id_Planta = @idPlanta)

    SELECT @Costo_TrabajoAnterior = @Costo_Trabajo
    ,@Costo_TrabajoActual =  Costo_Trabajo + (Costo_Trabajo * (@porcentaje/100))
    FROM Operativo WHERE Operativo.Mantenimiento_Id IN (SELECT Mantenimiento_Id FROM #CostoTrabajo)

    UPDATE Operativo SET Costo_Trabajo =  @Costo_TrabajoActual
    WHERE Operativo.Mantenimiento_Id IN (SELECT Mantenimiento_Id FROM #CostoTrabajo)

    -- lo mismo con la otra tabla Producto_Nutrientes y al final

    SELECT @Costo_TrabajoActual - @Costo_TrabajoAnterior AS AumentoCosto_Trabajo,@costo_usdActual - @costo_usdAnterior AS Aumentocosto_usd
```